# MVC3- Controller acces to several tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller

I am new to MVC, so something in following text may be confusing :D
Can you tell me, how to write controller for this
[database tables](http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/2520/databasez.png) with following code in models:

```
public class Kniha //in translate=book
{
    public int KnihaID { get; set; }
[MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage="Text knihy muze byt dlouhy max 100 znaku")]
    public string NazevKnihy { get; set; }

    public DateTime DatumVydani { get; set; }
    public string PopisKnihy { get; set; }
    public int PocetStran { get; set; }
    public int PocetKapitol { get; set; }
    public int AutorID { get; set; }
    public virtual Autor Autor { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Zanr> KnihaZanry { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Cenik> KnihaCeniky { get; set; }
}
public class Autor //in translate= Author
    {
        public int AutorID { get; set; }
        public string Jmeno { get; set; }
        public string Heslo { get; set; }
        public string Prijmeni { get; set; }
        public string Stat { get; set; }
        public string Mesto { get; set; }
        public string Ulice { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatumNarozeni { get; set; }
        public int TelefoniCislo { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Konto { get; set; }
        public string CeleJMeno
        {
            get
            {
                return Jmeno + " " + Prijmeni;
            }
        }
        public virtual ICollection<Kniha> NapsaneKnihy { get; set; }
    }
public class Cenik //in translate=price
    {
        public int CenikID { get; set; }
        public int AktualniCena { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatumCeny { get; set; }
        public Kniha Kniha { get; set; }
        public virtual Zamestnanec Zamestnanec { get; set; }
        public int ZamestnanecID { get; set; }
        public int KnihaID { get; set; }
    }

public class Zanr //in translate=genre
    {
        public int ZanrID { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage="Maximalni delka 50 znaku!!")]
        public string NazevZanru { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Kniha> ZanrKnihy { get; set; }
    }

public class AutorKnihaDalsi
    {
            public IEnumerable<Autor> Autori { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<Kniha> Knihy { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<Zanr> Zanry { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<Cenik> Ceniky { get; set; }

    }
```

This is controller, that doesnt work:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var viewInfo = new AutorKnihaDalsi();
        viewInfo.Knihy = db.Knihy.Include(c => c.Autor).Include(i=> i.KnihaCeniky.Select(c=> c.AktualniCena));
        return View(viewInfo);
    }
```

I wanted to print information about all books. In every book a wanted print their author, actual price and genre. But i dont know, how to do controller for this.
Secondly I want to ask how to execute saved t-sql procedures on my server( I found some informations here on this web, but it did not help).
EDIT: tables are now complete

Comment: `ActualniCena` doesn't appear in your classes. Can you complete this ? For the second part of your question, what are you using : Code First (I guess, but...), Model first, Database First ?

Comment: ActualniCena and all atributes are in my classes, I just didnt consider that is not important, so I didnt write it here. Second question.. in tutorials, they use Code First. For now I prefer the simpliest path to gain data from tables, because its school project and I dont have time :D

Comment: No error, I just dont know, how read data from tables.

Comment: I guess the best suggestion I can give is to go through a few more tutorials until you understand the data modeling a bit more. Start by showing the authors only, then add the rest of the data you are looking for.  Walk before you run, so to speak.